# Is there a way to apply a filter to a URL generated with the URL tag in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

For part of my user interface I need a URLencoded URL.

This code doesn't work, but it's intended to give an impression of what I'd like to do:

```
{% url 'team_event_calendar' id=team.id | urlencode %}
```

Basically, get a particular URL - in this case "team_event_calendar" for a particular team, and then URLencode it.

I suppose I could make a new version of the URL tag which URLencodes everything, but is there a way to do it with just Django's built-in tags?

Comment: You could try `{% with url 'team_event_calendar' id=team.id as myURL %}{{ myURL|urlencode }}{% endwith %}`

Comment: I get ```'with' expected at least one variable assignment```.